# Why this is an infinite loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

Why the loop goes on to infinity , I have put limits via n<6 , one more thing , the code prints 111111... . The output that I expect is 12345.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int n=1;
  do{
    while(n<6)
    printf("%d",n);
    n++;
  }
  while(n<6);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the internal loop (which was probably unintended) does not change `n`, which is always less than `6`.

Comment: In other words, you forget `{ ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why this is an infinite loop?

Because this:

```
do{
    while(n<6)
    printf("%d",n);
    n++;
}
...
```

Is actually this:

```
do{
    while(n<6) {
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    n++;
}
...
```

The code will never escape the "single statement while loop" just under the `do`. I would suggest that deleting it so that you only have one line that says `while(n<6)`, just above the `return`, will make your program function as you expect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Becuase in this loop only one statement is executed.

```
    while(n<6)
       printf("%d",n);
```

It is same as:

```
while(n<6)
{
   printf("%d",n);  
}
```

You enter this loop when `n == 1` which meets the loop condition condition

Answer (score 0):

The right code should be:

#include <stdio.h>

```
//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int n=1;
  do{
    printf("%d",n);
    n++;
  }
  while(n<6);

  return 0;
}
```

In addition, I find no reason to use a do-while statement.
A simple while would make the work:

```
int n=1
while(num<6)
{
  printf("%d",n);
  num++;
}
```

Also, for a known length of inputs, it is more right to use a for loop.